# Is it possible to calculate Hadwiger's number using $\Delta$ and $ \delta$?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G$ be a simple graph and denote Maximum degree and minimum degree by $\Delta$ and $\delta$ resp. Then

> Is it possible to calculate [Hadwiger's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_number) using $\Delta$ and $ \delta$?

Comment: I can't think so, e.g. take a triangle and add a vertex connected to just one vertex of the triangle. This has hadwiger number 3 and max degree 3, min degree 1. Now take a star with 4 vertices, this has hadwiger number 2 and the same max, min degree.

Comment: Thank you. So there is no way to connect this three number to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one direction, even for $3$-regular graphs, which have $\delta = \Delta = 3$, we can achieve a Hadwiger number which is as large as we like.

Just take a clique $K_n$ and replace each vertex by a cycle on $n-1$ vertices. Put a single edge joining every two different cycles, using a different vertex on each cycle every time. Here's a picture for $n=5$, with different cycles highlighted in different colors:

[image]

Contract the vertices of each cycle and you get $K_n$ again, so the Hadwiger number is at least $n$.

In the other direction, we can't put lower bounds on Hadwiger number from $\Delta$ alone - trees can have arbitrarily high $\Delta$ but still have a Hadwiger's number of $2$. However, if $\delta$ is large, then the Hadwiger number must also be large. As [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895600920136?via%3Dihub) shows, every graph with average degree at least $0.64t\log t$ has a $K_t$ minor, so certainly if $\delta$ is at least $0.64t\log t$, then the Hadwiger number is at least $t$.